# C# ComboBox GotFocus

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, focus

I have a C# `ComboBox` using WPF.  I have code that executes when the `ComboBox`'s `GotFocus` is activated.  The issue is that the `GotFocus` event is executed every time a selection is made from the `ComboBox`.  For example, the `GotFocus` is executed when you first click on the `ComboBox` and then when you make a selection even though you have not click on any other control.

Is it possible to prevent this event from firing if a selection is being made in the list or is there a flag or something else in the event handler that can be used to determine if the `GotFocus` event handler was fired as a result of the user selecting an item in the list?

Comment: Good info in this other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830510/issue-with-wpf-focus
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830510/issue-with-wpf-focus)

Answer (score 13):

You can solve this problem with next verification:

```
private void myComboBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(ComboBoxItem))
        return;
    //Your code here
}
```

This code will filter all focus events from items (because they use bubble routing event). But there is another problem - specific behaviour of WPF ComboBox focus: when you open drop-down list with items your ComboBox losing focus and items get. When you select some item - item losing focus and ComboBox get back. Drop-down list is like another control. You can see this by simple code:

```
private void myComboBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() != typeof(ComboBoxItem))
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Got " + DateTime.Now);
    }
}

private void myComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() != typeof(ComboBoxItem))
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Lost " + DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

So you will get anyway atleast two focus events: when you select ComboBox and when you selecting something in it (focus will return to ComboBox).

To filter returned focus after selecting item, you can try to use `DropDownOpened`/`DropDownClosed` events with some field-flag.

So the final code with only 1 event of getting focus:

```
private bool returnedFocus = false;

private void myComboBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() != typeof(ComboBoxItem) && !returnedFocus)
    {
        //Your code.
    }
}

private void myComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() != typeof(ComboBoxItem))
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
        returnedFocus = cb.IsDropDownOpen;
    }
}
```

Choose from this examples what you actually need more for your application.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work for editable comboboxes. Looks like `OriginalSource` in that case is a `TextBox` and not a `ComboBoxItem`. I have tried different variations of the above code to tackle the change but haven't succeeded yet. Will appreciate if you could look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too hot on WPF; but if you're trying to detect changes to the list (click on new value etc) you can use SelectedIndexChanged events..

On the other hand, if you really do want to know simply when the control is focussed, can you filter it by saying something like;

```
if (combo1.Focused && combo1.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
     ...
}
```

.. ? It really depends on what youre trying to detect, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is used is to determine whether the new focused element is an existing item in the combobox. If true then the LostFocus event should not be performed, because the combobox still has focus. Otherwise an element outside the combobox received focus.

In the code snipplet below I added the functionality in a custom combobox class

```
public class MyComboBox : System.Windows.Controls.Combobox
{
    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the new focused element and in case this is not an existing item of the current combobox then perform a lost focus command.
        //Otherwise the drop down items have been opened and is still focused on the current combobox
        var focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(FocusManager.GetFocusScope(this));
        if (!(focusedElement is ComboBoxItem && ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(focusedElement as ComboBoxItem) == this))
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            /* Your code here... */
        }
    }
}
```